# Which way to run javascript code in a python loop is more efficient?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm executing JavaScript code in python selenium while loop script, what would be the fastest way this loop could run?
python while-loop:

```
while not k.is_pressed('key'):
   driver.execute_script(js_code)
```

js_code  (Is looking for one button 'btn1', when it is available it clicks it and then another button should appear 'btn2' - click it too):

```
js_code = ''' function clickBtn2(){
let btn2 = document.querySelector(selector-btn2)
btn2.click()
}
function clickBtn1(){
let btn1 = document.querySelector(selector-btn1)
if (btn1){
btn1.click()
}
try{
        clickBtn2()
    }
    catch (err){}
}
clickBtn1()
'''
```

Would it run faster using js code this way?:

```
try{
   document.querySelector(selector-btn1).click()
}catch(err){}
try{
   document.querySelector(selector-btn2).click()
}catch(err){}
```

Iam looking for performance, need to look as many times as possible for both buttons in some time and click them, the btn2 is available in short load-depended time after clicking the first button.

Also I use key to break out of the while loop, using just simple

```
While True:
```

Would probably boost the performance more?

Comment: We are talking about nanoseconds differences here

Comment: Oh, in that case it probably is not that significant to care about, will stick with the shorter version.

Comment: We're talking about definitely more than nanoseconds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will click on whichever is available and not raise an error if they're both missing

```
document.querySelector(".btn1,.btn2")?.click()
```

Comment: Wow, that looks very good! Thank you will definitely use that one for the purpose.